# How to avoid texture stretching while rotating on 90 degrees? Generated texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, vector-mapping

I'm trying to simply just rotate the texture in the direction I desire (brick wall). The issue is when I rotate this generated texture it gets more and more stretched on some sides of the mesh.

[image: see?]

How to rotate texture and avoid this issue? I know it shouldn't be so so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did You try just using a UV-map? It gets a lot simpler and you don't need to mess with the mapping node.

Comment: I can't texture all objects with the same scale if i use UV map. I need generated type of the texture.